# Making a copy of IloCplex and then deleting a variable from the original IloCplex makes the variable unknown to the copy. Why?

Tags: cplex

Here I make a copy newplex of the IloCplex object cplex and then delete the variable x1 from cplex. The objective value of cplex changes and the objective value of newcplex is unchanged as expected. I get the following Output:

0.5  
0.5  
0.5

0.0  
0.5

But for some reason i get an IloCplexUnknownObjectException when i add System.out.println(newcplex.getValue(x1)) at the end of my code. Why?

```
IloCplex cplex=new IloCplex();
IloObjective kosten= cplex.addMinimize();
IloRange nb=cplex.addRange(0, 1);
IloColumn col= cplex.column(nb,1).and(cplex.column(kosten,1));
IloNumVar x1=cplex.numVar(col,0.5, 1);

IloCopyManager cm = new IloCopyManager(cplex);

IloCplex newcplex = new IloCplex();

newcplex.add((IloAddable) nb.makeCopy(cm));
newcplex.add((IloAddable) kosten.makeCopy(cm));

cplex.solve();
newcplex.solve();

System.out.println(cplex.getObjValue());
System.out.println(newcplex.getObjValue());
System.out.println(newcplex.getValue(x1));

cplex.delete(x1);

cplex.solve();
newcplex.solve();


System.out.println(cplex.getObjValue());
System.out.println(newcplex.getObjValue());
```